# Checking if a ElementCollection map has a matching entry

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpql

I have an

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(
  name = "orgattributes", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "org_id"))
@MapKeyColumn(name = "attribute")
@Column(name = "value")
Map<String,String> attributes
```

and I want to use JPQL if the object has a given entry in the attributes table

I tried the following (among others) in Spring-Data all failed

```
@Query("from Organization o join o.attributes a where ?1 in entry(a)")
List<Organization> findOrganizationsWithAttribute(Map.Entry<String,String> attributeValue) ;

default List<Organization> findOrganizationsWithAttribute(String attribute, String value) {
    return findOrganizationsWithAttribute(Map.entry(attribute, value));
}
```

Using maps

```
@Query("from Organization o join o.attributes a where ?1 in entry(a)")
List<Organization> findOrganizationsWithAttribute(Map<String,String> attributeValue) ;

default List<Organization> findOrganizationsWithAttribute(String attribute, String value) {
    return findOrganizationsWithAttribute(Map.of(attribute, value));
}
```

My original one which works if there is only one attribute.

```
@Query("from Organization o join o.attributes a where key(a) = ?1 and value(a) = ?2")
List<Organization> findOrganizationsWithAttribute(Map<String, String> attributeValue);
```

The SQL equivalent I am trying to do is

```
select * from organization o where o.orgid in (select orgid from orgattribute a where a.attribute = ?1 and a.value = ?2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard way doing this with `List`'s or `Set`'s is `MEMBER OF`. I have never tried it with `Map`'s. But you can try

`@Query("SELECT o FROM Organization o where ?1 MEMBER OF o.attributes")`

As the parameter value try the key or the value of the map. Key might work.

Comment: I need it with both key and value though.